# Make document.hasFocus return 'true' only once, then return 'true' or 'false' normally

Tags: javascript

I'm using `document.hasFocus = function(){return true;}` to force a return `true` as soon as the page is opened.

The problem (which is actually the default behavior of this code) is that as soon as this code is executed it becomes permanent, that is, it will always return `true`, even if the document is out of focus.

My intention is for this `true` return to happen only once when opening the page, then the boolean should be according to the user's actions (`false` when the document is out of focus and `true` when the document is out of focus) that is, the default behavior of the `document.hasFocus()` method).

I don't have much theoretical knowledge about JavaScript, but I tried the following code to resume the standard operation of the `document.hasFocus()` method; none of them worked.

1: `document.hasFocus();`

2: `document.hasFocus = function(){return};`

3: `document.hasFocus = function(){return document.hasFocus};`

Is there any way to resume the default behavior of `document.hasFocus()` after I have already set its return to `true` or `false`?

Comment: Do you mind sharing more around the actual reason why you would want to alter the default `document.hasFocus` functionality? Like what logic depends on the document (or part of it) being focused?

Comment: I have a code that counts how long the user has been with my website in focus. Samsung Internet and the built-in browsers of the FB and Instagram apps start web pages with the `document.hasFocus()` method set to `false` until the user taps the screen. This makes my time counting code almost useless since most of my website traffic comes from ads on FB and Instagram.